# How to make a python cmd module command that runs python code

Tags: python

So I'm messing around with the "cmd" module for python, I want a command where you can type "python" and then it opens a python command line. Sort of like how an actual command line would.

Here's my current code.

```
import cmd

class pythonCmd(cmd.Cmd):
    def do_(self, args):     # <--- I want this command to have it so you don't type a key word
        exec(args)

class cmdLine(cmd.Cmd):
    
        
    def do_python(self, args):
        prompt = pythonCmd()
        prompt.prompt = 'python> '
        prompt.cmdloop('Python 3.8.2')
    
    
prompt = cmdLine()
prompt.prompt = '> '
prompt.cmdloop('Command line starting . . .')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you have to use cmd module or not. But there are much better modules similar to cmd. Modules such as subprocess, os and etc.
I recently used subprocess module, try it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that isn't an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:
Instead of running your program that opens a shell that can take both python commands and potentially your own commands,
Run python shell, import your program module- you have native python shell that can run python code.
Add support of additional commands by implementing a function like cmd(args) which you can call from the shell. You may need to work on your module to simplify using it in interactive python shell by providing @aliases”to existing functions etc..

Answer (score 0):

With do_shell function you can use it with "!" syntax. For example

```
> !print("Henlo world")
```

This would print it, you can use other commands too.